# I need a webpage to host my javascript!

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

Does anyone know a website that hosts javascripts on their page?

I have a research project that needs to collect some RTT from all over the world and compare them together. I have written the javascript code for that but I do not have a high hit rate website to put it on to collect data. I know it is a little bit odd question to ask, but do you know any website or any trick that can help me?

Note that the script would not do any harm to anybody! :-)

Thanks,

---

Decad is right, I basically need some people to put my script on their "high-hit rate" website ... so I can collect data from large number of clients...

Of coarse, the script is run on the background with no harm to the page. It basically measures some RTT and submit it to a server.

I already have some pages, but they barely got a hit from outside!

Thanks,

Comment: Any webhoster that just supports hosting HTML pages will do.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is executed client side, so it doesn't matter which host you use. It matters more about what browser the user uses to view your site, but in today's modern world, I wouldn't worry about that too much.

Comment: I think you're missing the point, he wants a host that allows the hosting of his JavaScript to get his script run on a large number of clients.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend hosting on Amazon S3 or Rackspace Cloud if you need high availability.

Otherwise, you could post it on a site like Ripway. 100 MB of free hosting, though I haven't used them personally.
http://www.ripway.com/

If you're trying to pull in a common Javascript library, check to see if Google already hosts it:
http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for free hosting try out http://www.000webhost.com/